# Crear formulario preferencias usuario con checkbox

Tags: django, django-forms

quiero crear un formulario del tipo:

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Deportes:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="futbol" value="3"> futbol<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="basket" value="4"> basket<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="natacion" value="6"> natación<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="voley" value="7"> voley<br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Música:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="clasica" value="8"> Clásica<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rock" value="5"> Rock<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pop" value="10"> Pop<br>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="guardar">
</form>
```

en models.py tengo:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(_('Surname'), blank=True, max_length=255)
    preferences = models.ManyToManyField(Preferences, related_name='preferences_user', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': self.username})

class Preferences(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Preference'), blank=False, max_length=100)
    parent = models.IntegerField(_('Parent preference'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('parent',)
```

En la tabla "Preferences" tengo los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
ID   name    parent
1    Deportes 0
2    Música   0
3    futbol   1
4    basket   1
5    Rock     2
etc...
```

he probado de varias maneras con UpdateView y forms.. etc y no consigo hacer que  las preferencias en las que  parent == 0  ponerlas como "legend" en el en la etiqueta html "fieldset"

Gracias

Vale, añado la vista y form

forms.py

```
class PreferencesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('preferences',)
        widgets = {'preferences': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'mi-clase'})}
```

views.py

```
class UserPreferences(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = User
    template_name_suffix = '_preferences_form'
    form_class = PreferencesForm

    # send the user back to their own page after a successful update
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail',
                       kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):
        # Only get the User record for the user making the request
        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserPreferences, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form1'] = Preferences.objects.all()
        return context
```

Template

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:update_preferences' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No termino de entender tu consulta, podrías explicarlo un poco mejor?
Sería bueno que incluyas el código de tu template y la vista de ser posible.

Comment: Hola @PanchoJay , pues no se como hacer para que en el template  poder saber si el campo parent es 0, para así poder agrupar todas las subcategorías con la etiqueta html fieldset, Según lo he hecho funciona correctamente, a mi me interesa agruparlo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el template puedes preguntar por campos especificos del modelo de la siguiente manera (dado que el queryset lo enviaste como form1 en el contexto desde la vista y que son todos los objetos debes iterar), aqui entonces por cada usuario, iteramos las preferencias encabezado y luego dentro de el, las preferencias del manytomany:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for preference in preferences %}
        {% if preference.parent == 0 %}
            <fieldset>
              <legend>{{ preference.name }}</legend>
              {% for pref in user.preferences.all %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="futbol" value="3">{{ pref.name }}<br>
            {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, efectivamente el form1 es una prueba que había hecho añadiendo     "def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):" a la vista, si lo quito, me crea todos los campos con {{ form }} pero lo que no se es como acceder, si se puede, a los objetos que se crean desde el forms.py par apoder iterear por ellos.

Comment: @agus Pero te funciono para lo que necesitabas ?

Comment: no, porque en ese contexto "form1" no puedo saber cuales son las preferencias que tiene seleccionadas cada usuario

Comment: @agus Pero por que preferencias de usuario ?, si te entiendo, tienes un modelo llamado preferences donde hay un campo parent, cuando mandas en form1 el queryset con objects.all tienes todos los registros de dicho modelo. y en mi codigo estas iterando cada uno y preguntando si el parent es 0, de esa forma por cada uno que cumpla la condición de parent =0 puedes ejecutar lo que necesites.

Comment: claro, pero para mostrar los checkbox marcados que el usuario ya había seleccionado, tendría que hacer otra consulta a las preferencias seleecionadas actualente por  el usuario y comparar con todos los registros de la tabla preferences en el template y marcar el check o no.

Comment: @agus, pero entonces tu necesidad es diferente...necesitas es mostrar por usuario, que preferencias tuvo ?, donde esta la relación de usuario con preferencias en el modelo ?

Comment: está en la class User: preferences = models.ManyToManyField(Preferences, related_name='preferences_user', blank=True)

Comment: @agus Disculpa la tardanza, si creo entender lo que necesitas ahora se haria como actualice mi respuesta, verifica y me confirmas.